# Star pattern in C

Tags: c, algorithm

I am trying to solve this patter, The input from the user is the max length of stars..
 For example

[image]
The image is for inputs 11 and 12
[image]

Other pattern examples

(9) 1-5-9-5-9-5-1
(11) 1-5-9-11-9-11-9-5-1
(12) 2-6-10-12-10-12-10-6-2
(16) 2-6-10-14-16-14-10-14-16-14-10-6-2

If the number is odd, the stars start from one, incrementing by four on each line, but when the increment becomes greater than the max length only incrementing by two.. If the number is even, the stars start from two but follows the same incrementing way.

So, what I tried to do is work on the first upper part first then mirror it later, here is my code FOR ODD numbers only, was planning to work on even numbers after this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int stars, spaces, maxlen, rows;
    int spac=0, star=1;
    scanf("%d", &maxlen);

    for (rows=1;rows<=maxlen;rows++){
        for(spaces=1; spaces<=(maxlen/2)-spac; spaces++){
            printf(" ");
        }

        for(stars=1; stars<=star; stars++){
            printf("*");
        }

        printf("\n");

        if (star>=maxlen)
            break;

        if (star==9)
            star += 2;
        else
            star += 4;

        spac+=2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the code is working for 1,9,11 but the problem when i input from 13+ it doesn't give me the results i expected...

Anyhelp how I can solve this, and I will appreciate comment on my approach, is it a good approach or is there another method of solving patterns that i should learn, to solve this irregular patterns easier?

Comment: do you have some propper definition of the algorithm/pattern/shape/whatever?

Comment: @V-X I have just uploaded a sample image

Comment: It doesn't work for me with n other than one.

Comment: Oh I understand. You have pictures and you want to write the code for it... Cool, but how did you get the pictures and how do you expect the other pictures to look?

Comment: @V-X the code is just for the upper part, before mirroring... so it won't give the actual image like the one in the pattern... Actually, i don't need the code, just the concept and the correction of my code if possible to get the desired result so that i can mirror it after

Comment: you just need to have an algorithm to generate the sequence and the printing will be smooth and easy at the end.

Comment: even n is the same as n-1 just with one line of * in the middle. is it correct?
you allways increase 4 until you reach the width of n?
and the pattern is horizontally and vertically symmetrical?

Comment: The images and the numeric sequences for 11 and 12 don't seem to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see the pattern, there are two overlapping squares of * symbols with trimmed edges, which overflow the line lengths (the longest line has only two more * than the previous line)
the second thing is that it is not sure, how distant those two squares are.

I wrote something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define OVERLAPP 1

int linesCount(int maxlen)
{
    return maxlen + maxlen%2 + (OVERLAPP);
}

int get_stars(int maxlen, int line)
{
    if (2 * line > linesCount(maxlen))
    {
       return get_stars(maxlen, linesCount(maxlen) - line - 1);
    }
    else
    {
        int stars;
        stars = 2 - maxlen%2;
        stars += 4 * line;
        if (stars > maxlen)
        {
            if (stars - maxlen < 3)
            {
                stars = maxlen;
            }
            else
            {
                stars = 2 * maxlen - stars + 4;
            }
        }
        return stars;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int maxlen;
    int maxlines;
    int line;
    int column;
    int current_stars;

    scanf("%d", &maxlen);
    maxlines = linesCount(maxlen);

    for(line = 0; line < maxlines; line++)
    {
        current_stars = get_stars(maxlen, line);
        for(column = 0; 2 * column + 1 < maxlen - current_stars; column++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for(column = 0; column < current_stars; column++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        for(column = 0; 2 * column + 1 < maxlen - current_stars; column++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf(" %d\n", current_stars);
    }

}
```

This gives following results:

```
gcc golf.c; seq 20 | xargs -I num echo "echo;echo "--------num---------";echo; echo num | ./a.exe" | bash

--------1---------

* 1
* 1
* 1

--------2---------

** 2
** 2
** 2

--------3---------

 *  1
*** 3
 *  1
*** 3
 *  1

--------4---------

 **  2
**** 4
 **  2
**** 4
 **  2

--------5---------

  *   1
***** 5
***** 5
  *   1
***** 5
***** 5
  *   1

--------6---------

  **   2
****** 6
****** 6
  **   2
****** 6
****** 6
  **   2

--------7---------

   *    1
 *****  5
******* 7
 *****  5
   *    1
 *****  5
******* 7
 *****  5
   *    1

--------8---------

   **    2
 ******  6
******** 8
 ******  6
   **    2
 ******  6
******** 8
 ******  6
   **    2

--------9---------

    *     1
  *****   5
********* 9
********* 9
  *****   5
    *     1
  *****   5
********* 9
********* 9
  *****   5
    *     1

--------10---------

    **     2
  ******   6
********** 10
********** 10
  ******   6
    **     2
  ******   6
********** 10
********** 10
  ******   6
    **     2

--------11---------

     *      1
   *****    5
 *********  9
*********** 11
 *********  9
   *****    5
     *      1
   *****    5
 *********  9
*********** 11
 *********  9
   *****    5
     *      1

--------12---------

     **      2
   ******    6
 **********  10
************ 12
 **********  10
   ******    6
     **      2
   ******    6
 **********  10
************ 12
 **********  10
   ******    6
     **      2

--------13---------

      *       1
    *****     5
  *********   9
************* 13
************* 13
  *********   9
    *****     5
      *       1
    *****     5
  *********   9
************* 13
************* 13
  *********   9
    *****     5
      *       1

--------14---------

      **       2
    ******     6
  **********   10
************** 14
************** 14
  **********   10
    ******     6
      **       2
    ******     6
  **********   10
************** 14
************** 14
  **********   10
    ******     6
      **       2

--------15---------

       *        1
     *****      5
   *********    9
 *************  13
*************** 15
 *************  13
   *********    9
     *****      5
       *        1
     *****      5
   *********    9
 *************  13
*************** 15
 *************  13
   *********    9
     *****      5
       *        1

--------16---------

       **        2
     ******      6
   **********    10
 **************  14
**************** 16
 **************  14
   **********    10
     ******      6
       **        2
     ******      6
   **********    10
 **************  14
**************** 16
 **************  14
   **********    10
     ******      6
       **        2

--------17---------

        *         1
      *****       5
    *********     9
  *************   13
***************** 17
***************** 17
  *************   13
    *********     9
      *****       5
        *         1
      *****       5
    *********     9
  *************   13
***************** 17
***************** 17
  *************   13
    *********     9
      *****       5
        *         1

--------18---------

        **         2
      ******       6
    **********     10
  **************   14
****************** 18
****************** 18
  **************   14
    **********     10
      ******       6
        **         2
      ******       6
    **********     10
  **************   14
****************** 18
****************** 18
  **************   14
    **********     10
      ******       6
        **         2

--------19---------

         *          1
       *****        5
     *********      9
   *************    13
 *****************  17
******************* 19
 *****************  17
   *************    13
     *********      9
       *****        5
         *          1
       *****        5
     *********      9
   *************    13
 *****************  17
******************* 19
 *****************  17
   *************    13
     *********      9
       *****        5
         *          1

--------20---------

         **          2
       ******        6
     **********      10
   **************    14
 ******************  18
******************** 20
 ******************  18
   **************    14
     **********      10
       ******        6
         **          2
       ******        6
     **********      10
   **************    14
 ******************  18
******************** 20
 ******************  18
   **************    14
     **********      10
       ******        6
         **          2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that is better approach to divide problem in many parts. For example

1. Function that takes number of starts to draw in one line and max width and then it draws one line of starts

   ```
   void draw_line_of_stars(unsigned int stars, unsigned int max_width)
   ```
2. Function that takes line and returns number of starts to draw

   ```
   unsigned int get_n_stars(unsigned int line, unsigned int starsize)
   ```

   - this function is probably assembled from more functions to deal with symmetry for instance
3. Function that will draw whole star using this two functions.

I suggest this approach, because you can test each function separately to check if works correctly and then assemble them in this more complex solution.

Comment: Thanks, let me try to create different functions. I agree its a pain sometimes to put everything in the main function

Answer (score 0):

Wow I thought this was not possible. 
I have one code for 2, 4, 2,4,2.

## include

```
int main(void) {
    int i, j;
    int NumMax = 5;
    for(i = 0; i < NumMax; i++)
    {
        if((i%2) == 0)
        {
            printf(" ");
            for(j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                printf("*");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                printf("*");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one did not want to edit my so called answer but the pattern 1, 6, 6, 1, 6, 6, 1, on the for loop the outer where the lines that prints 6 are multiples of 30. Here is the code and hopes someone calls it stupid.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, j, m, k;
    int numMax = 6;

    for(i = 1; i < (numMax * 2) - 4; i++)
    {
        if(((30 % i) == 0) && (i != 1))
        {
            for(k = 1; k < 2; k++)
            {
                for(m = 1; m <= numMax; m++)
                {
                     printf("*");
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(j = 1; j < 2; j++)
            {
                printf("  **");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```